# Redux, storing data outside of redux store

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I'm making a calendar app.

When a user navigates to next month, 
I want to initiate actions to fetch data.

The list of actions to fire are dynamic in nature, it depends on the currently mounted components.

I'm currently storing the list of actions to fire in a list (in a module)

I feel I'm doing something not conventional by storing data outside of redux store.
But I read somewhere that redux store is supposed to hold stuff that is serializable. And my actions (which is actually action creators that will be used by redux-thunk) are not serializable.

So question is,

1. is it a bad idea to store data outside of redux store, if so why?
2. why is it a bad idea to store non-serializable data in the redux store?

The action creator (which I store in the list) looks like the following

```
function foo(params) {
  var url = "some-url"
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
     fetch(url, params).then(..).then(dispatch(someAction))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your list isn't data, it's code. It's a list of commands which is all code really is. You can store this outside of state.

But your list should be JavaScript. You can branch with `if`, and use `switch` for complex Turing complete dynamism. It should probably just be a thunked action creator.

As for why your state should be serializable: it's so you can serialize it. There are tools and modules that need the state to be serializable, but it's optional. It forces your state to be data, however.

That said, when using Immutable.js, state is now a complex object. You can still serialize it, but not with `JSON.stringify`. So if you can write a function, any function, that can serialize state, you can them claim state is serializable.

Answer (score 0):

While there technically isn't anything "wrong" with the approach you're currently taking, it's a bit of an anti-pattern. Normally, if you want to execute some logic based on certain conditions, you wouldn't do it by storing the functions to call in an array; you would of course use `if` and `switch` as the above answer points out, so you shouldn't do it here.

Why not add a middleware for asynchronous actions, and have this pick up the action dispatched when a user navigates to the next month. This middleware would call a handler for this action, inside of which you can dispatch the other actions you want to. This seems way cleaner to me anyway.